# Expandable content in tables using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been following the tutorials for AngularJS over on [Egghead](https://egghead.io/lessons). Things are going pretty good, until I decided to try to combine some concepts.

My main.js is located [here](http://pastebin.com/s9LhxFU0), due to the fact of the size of the file.

And here's my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Egghead Videos</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="foundation/css/foundation.min.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="CardsCtrl">

      <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="set in cards.sets | orderBy:'releaseDate'">
            <td>{{set.name}}</td>
            <td>{{set.code}}</td>
            <td>{{set.releaseDate}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, as you can see, I have it set up right now to display the set, code, and releaseDate in a table using `ng-repeat`. What I'm trying to accomplish is every time that you click on a set name, it expands and shows all the cards in that set, showing the name and card number. I've tried wrapping the table in the 'zippy' attribute like the tutorial was doing, but that accomplished nothing. Any ideas or suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: so if I understand correctly, you need an accordion control that can collapse and provide a list of items?

Answer (score 0):

So, I'll do this in the table format, but it is weird because it would be within the confines of the first td; you might want to consider a different layout.  For visualization sake, I'll just make the set.name into a clickable link, but I believe it can be any element.

Please note that this is not tested; best practice that I've seen on here would be for the question to include either a plnkr.co or jsfiddle.net reference.

View:

```
<td>
  <a href="" ng-click="showThisRow(set)">
    {{set.name}}
  </a>
  <p ng-repeat="card in set.cards" ng-if="showRow">
    {{card.number}} : {{card.name}}
  </p>
</td>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.showThisRow = function (whichSet) {
  if (whichSet.showRow == true) {
  whichSet.showRow = false;
  } else {
  whichSet.showRow = true;
  }
}
```

Notes: What this is doing is a nested ng-repeat call, which is shown only if the value of the showRow variable is true.  showRow can be instantiated as a method of set (an instance of the first ng-repeat) via the ng-click call, even without being specified within the controller.

I don't know if Angular provides something similar to toggle in jQuery; it would be appreciated if someone who knows that could comment as well.

Answer (score 0):

The trick with selection of individual items of `ng-repeat`, is the inclusion of an `controller` in the same element as the `ng-repeat`. The ng-repeat dedicated controller will contain all the new items generated by the iteration, `ng-click` calling a function in that controller will do the item selection.

view:

```
<div ng-controller="TableCtrl">
  <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Company</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ng-repeat="i in invoices" 
             ng-controller="RowCtrl" 
             ng-click="toggleRow()" 
             ng-switch on="isSelected()">
        <tr>
            <td>{{i.name}}</td>
            <td>{{i.company}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-switch-when="true">
            <td>{{i.invoice}}</td>
            <td>{{i.units}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Controllers:

```
.value('invoices', [
  { name:'Jack', company:'Blue Widget Co', invoice:'$3,000,000', units: '555'},
  { name:'Jill', company:'Red widget Co', invoice:'$2,000,000', units: '777' }
])

.controller('TableCtrl', function ($scope, invoices) {
  $scope.invoices = invoices;
})

.controller('RowCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.toggleRow = function () {
    $scope.selected = !$scope.selected;
  };

  $scope.isSelected = function (i) {
    return $scope.selected;
  };
});
```

In the RowCtrl, take note of `i` from `ng-repeat="i in invoices"`:

```
$scope.isSelected = function (i) {
  return $scope.selected;
};
```

Heres a working [expandable table demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/kA0BYw?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

@cheekybastard This can be simplified further by using a directive.

Directive:

```
app.directive('cdToggleOnClick', function () 
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: 
        {
            cdToggleOnClick: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                if (scope.cdToggleOnClick === true)
                {
                  scope.cdToggleOnClick = false; 
                }
                else
                {
                  scope.cdToggleOnClick = true;
                }
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <table border=1>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="i in invoices" cd-toggle-on-click="toggleRow">
            <td>{{i.name}}</td>
            <td>{{i.company}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="toggleRow">
            <td>{{i.invoice}}</td>
            <td>{{i.units}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.invoices = [
    { name:'Jack', company:'Blue Widget Co', invoice:'$3,000,000', units: '555'},
    { name:'phil', company:'green Widget Co', invoice:'$1,000,000', units: '545'},
    { name:'Jill', company:'Red widget Co', invoice:'$2,000,000', units: '777' }
  ];
});
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gvtb37znLH08papCemER?p=preview)